# Знаки препинания, несколько предложений

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> Девушка, а девушка, а мы с вами случайно не знакомы? А нам, тем, кто беден, приходится работать. Данный прибор помогает этим — тем, что справа, — дышать. То, что мы со временем начинаем понимать тех, с кем работаем, (—) это я знаю. Прибор может сканировать только металл, и только небольшой массы. Он не обязан отчитываться мне как директору. Эти несколько десятков, а если повезет, то и сотен лет — будешь жить припеваючи. У них, у рабочих, есть свои чувства. Эту стену невозможно обойти, что с одной, что с другой стороны.

Правильно ли расставлены знаки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Девушка, а девушка, а мы с вами случайно не знакомы?

А нам, тем, кто беден, приходится работать. А нам — тем, кто беден, — приходится работать.

Данный прибор помогает этим — тем, что справа, — дышать. Стиль желательно проверить по контексту.

То, что мы со временем начинаем понимать тех, с кем работаем, — это я знаю. Запятая и тире как единый знак.

Прибор может сканировать только металл, и только небольшой массы. Присоединительный союз, наличие паузы

Он не обязан отчитываться мне как директору. Значение "в качестве".

Эти несколько десятков — а если повезет, то и сотен лет — будешь жить припеваючи.

У них, у рабочих, есть свои чувства.

Эту стену невозможно обойти — как с одной, так и  с другой стороны.

Comment: "Запятая и тире как единый знак". Можно подробней об этом? Я думал, каждый знак по своей причине.

Comment: Предложение нестандартное, в нем повтор местоимений "то - это", указывающих на одно и то же содержание. А при повторе можно считать, что ставится единый знак (у Розенталя есть такая  тема). Но именно такого повтора у него нет, поэтому  здесь можно считать по-разному. Наверное, удобнее думать, что каждый знак по своей причине, а определять структуру предложения и вовсе не надо, никто и внимания не обратит. Всё просто: запятая закрывает придаточное, тире ставится перед ЭТО,